# How to set the label inside the box(image added below), e.g. red box label : "2 issues"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image: Red,Yellow and Green box]

Red should have label inside it as "2 Issues", Yellow box :"4 Issues"...
I am unable to add css for this scenario.

In the below code i tried to add the label but it didn't work, I am unable to find which attribute should be used for displaying a text inside the box;

```
content += "<tr rowspan = \"3\"><td><div class=\"project-name\">"+args.chart.chartWidth[i].project+"</td>";
content += "<td colspan = \"5\"><div class=\"box-container"+i+"\"><div class=\"box"+i+" red" +i+ "\"></div><div class=\"box"+i+" yellow" +i+ "\"></div><div class=\"box"+i+" green" +i+ "\"></div></div></td></br></tr>"; 
content += "<style type=\"text/css\"> ";
content +=".box-container"+i+"{   padding: 10px;display: table-cell;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle; }";
content +=".box"+i+"{float: left; box-shadow:3px 3px 2px #666767; height:30px;}";
content += ".red" +i+" { width: " + redWid + "px; background-color:#ff0000; **label:"2Issues"** }";
content += ".yellow"+i+" { width: " + yellowWid + "px; background-color:#ffff00; **label:"3Issues"**  }";
content += ".green"+i+" { width: " + greenWid + "px; background-color:#00ff00; **label:"4Issues"** }";
```

Comment: i tried to add the label but it didn't work, I am unable to find which attribute should be used for displaying a text inside the box;

Answer (score 0):

Just by adding the text between the div's of the red,green and yellow displayed the label inside the box.